# VBA - paste multiple Excel ranges into Outlook as images

Tags: microsoft-excel, email, vba

Trying to create an Outlook email that has Excel ranges pasted as jpg in the email, along with text before and after. Something like:

Text

Image 1

Image 2

More Text

However, I cannot figure out how to convert Excel ranges to images and paste them in the Outlook email without overriding text there. Current code is below (anonymized), focus on .HTMLBody part. Feels like this should be simple but I can't figure out the exact code.

```
Sub GenerateEmail()
 
  ' Declare variables
  Dim outlookApp As Object
  Dim MItem As Object
  Dim Recipients As String
  Dim Subject As String
  Dim Body1 As String
  Dim Body2 As String
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim EmailList As Range
  Dim Cell As Range
  Dim table1 As Range
  Dim table2 As Range
  Dim ExcRng As Range
  
 
  ' Set the email subject and body
  Subject = "Subject"
  Body1 = Sheet1.Range("B11")
  Body2 = Sheet1.Range("B12")
 
  ' Set the range that includes the list of email addresses
  Set EmailList = Sheet1.Range("b11:b11")
  
  ' Copy the range as an image and paste it into the email
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
  Set table1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1:I21")
  Set table2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet3").Range("A4:W41")
  table1.Copy
  table2.Copy
 
  ' Create a new Outlook email
  Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set MItem = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
 
  ' Add the recipients, subject, and body to the email
With MItem
    .To = ws.Range("G4")
    .Subject = ws.Range("B7")
    
    'Add message before ranges
    .HTMLBody = ws.Range("B9") & "<br>" & "<br>" & ws.Range("B10") _
    **& RangeToJPG(table2) _
    & RangeToJPG(table1) _**
    & "<br>" & "<br>" & "<br>" & "<br>" & ws.Range("B11")
    
    .Display
End With

Set Message = Nothing
Set Email = Nothing

End Sub
```

For RangetoJPG I tried using the below code from another user. However, it creates a new email for each image, which I don't want. I cannot determine how to keep everything within the same Outlook email item.

```
Function RangeToJPG(rng As Range)

'Copy range of interest
rng.Copy

'Open a new mail item
Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set OutMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'Get its Word editor
OutMail.Display
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
Set wordDoc = OutMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

'To paste as picture
wordDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture

End Function
```

Comment: If worst comes to worst, you can always use AHK to automate this.  Excel has pretty good synergy with AHK, I often use them together for automating data entry.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I would guess you would incorporate the `<img>` HTML tag to the message part of your email. Now what I am unsure about is to make that image a part of your email (attachment maybe) and then reference that in the `<img>`. if you want, just right click on an HTML email and view source. Hopefully, I pointed you in the right direction.

Comment: I'd use Ron de Bruins [RangetoHTML](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm) code.